# How to ensure a cypress test in one file runs before another cypress test in another file

Tags: javascript, parallel-processing, mocha.js, cypress

I have a cypress Test A that creates an account and then another cypress Test B that deletes it. Cypress Test B will fail if cypress Test A isn't run before it.

I am currently running tests across 10 VMs and my tests are split by timings in CI.

Is this at all possible?  How do I ensure Test A runs before Test B?

Or is there anyway to pass test B by default if Test A hasn't run yet ?

Comment: Brute force comes to mind - add enough retries that TestB will eventually pass. But that's ugly, better to let TestB seed the account before trying to delete it.

Comment: Also ***pass test B by default*** - is it really a test if you do that?

Comment: Seed the account?  I would like an option to specify is test A has already been run then expect test b to fail

Comment: If they are in separate describe blocks or test files, then create a new account in `before()`/`beforeEach()` block of Test B. Don't make your tests dependent on others.

Comment: This idea is a proposed workaround while we make separate data so tests don't collide.

Comment: Specify the order using `testFiles` in the configuration. `specPattern` if you're using Cypress 10. Example set in `cypress.config.js` following property `specPattern: ['cypress/e2e/testA', 'cypress/e2e/testB']`. Along with this, ensure that you are not using the same user on all VMs. You can do that by changing for example the email to have a suffix of a random number. For example, use `johndoe+3848@gmail.com` where 3848 is a random generated number. You can see in my boilerplate [how I approached this](https://github.com/optimumqa/cypress-boilerplate/blob/main/cypress/support/helpers.ts#L21)